# Aplicar estilos de acuerdo a las estructura HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html5

lo que sucede es que estoy tratando de aplicar unos estilos a un `SVG` de acuerdo a su estructura, debo validar por ejemplo que si su etiqueta `path` tiene el atributo `fill` me le aplique unos estilos, y si no la tiene, que no los aplique y así con todos los `SVG` que tenga la pagina, por algún motivo no me está funcionando bien (lo puse en un `case` por que no es solo al `path` sino a todas las etiquetas como `circle`, `line` entre otras), he tratado de varias formas y no me funciona, pongo un código de lo que tengo, muchas gracias de ante mano para ayudarme a solucionar y ver si tengo algo malo en la lógica.

```js
$("svg").each(function() {
  caseElement = $(this).children()[0].nodeName;
  console.log(caseElement);

  switch (caseElement) {
    case 'path':
      colorFill = $(this).attr('fill');
      if (colorFill !== undefined || colorFill !== 'none') {
        $(this).css('fill', 'red');
      }
      break;
    case 'circle':
      alert('2');
      break;
    case 'line':
      alert('3');
      break;
    case 'dojo':
      alert('4');
      break;
  }

});
```

```css
svg {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>



<svg id="Capa_1" version="1.1" baseProfile="tiny" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 91.5 91.5" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#C4D600" d="M45.7,0C20.5,0,0,20.5,0,45.7s20.5,45.7,45.7,45.7C71,91.5,91.5,71,91.5,45.7C91.5,20.5,71.1,0,45.7,0                                  C45.8,0,45.8,0,45.7,0z M45.7,83.9c-21.1,0-38.1-17.1-38.1-38.1S24.7,7.6,45.7,7.6s38.1,17.1,38.1,38.1l0,0                                  C83.8,66.8,66.8,83.8,45.7,83.9z"></path>
<path fill="#C4D600" d="M60.3,53.7c-8.1,8-21.1,8-29.2,0c-1.5-1.5-3.9-1.5-5.5,0c-1.5,1.5-1.5,3.9,0,5.5c11,11.1,28.8,11.2,39.9,0.2                                  c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2c1.5-1.5,1.5-3.9,0-5.5C64.3,52.2,61.8,52.2,60.3,53.7L60.3,53.7z"></path>
<circle fill="#C4D600" cx="62.4" cy="32.6" r="4"></circle>
<circle fill="#C4D600" cx="29.4" cy="32.6" r="4"></circle>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hice la respuesta mia basada en el codigo de tu pregunta, el problema radicaba en que los elementos por los que estas preguntando son hijos de la etiqueta svg, por tanto, debes obtener sus hijos, recorrerlos y en cada iteración ir preguntando con el switch por el tipo, ya que como lo tenias anteriormente solo llegabas hasta el path, que era el primer hijo $(this).children()[0]

```js
$("svg").each(function() {
 $(this).children().each(function(index, child){
    caseElement = child.nodeName;

    switch (caseElement) {
      case 'path':
        colorFill = $(this).attr('fill');
        if (colorFill !== undefined || colorFill !== 'none') {
          $(this).css('fill', 'red');
        }
        break;
      case 'circle':
        alert('2');
        break;
      case 'line':
        alert('3');
        break;
      case 'dojo':
        alert('4');
        break;
    }
});

  });
```

```css
svg {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>



<svg id="Capa_1" version="1.1" baseProfile="tiny" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 91.5 91.5" xml:space="preserve">
<path fill="#C4D600" d="M45.7,0C20.5,0,0,20.5,0,45.7s20.5,45.7,45.7,45.7C71,91.5,91.5,71,91.5,45.7C91.5,20.5,71.1,0,45.7,0                                  C45.8,0,45.8,0,45.7,0z M45.7,83.9c-21.1,0-38.1-17.1-38.1-38.1S24.7,7.6,45.7,7.6s38.1,17.1,38.1,38.1l0,0                                  C83.8,66.8,66.8,83.8,45.7,83.9z"></path>
<path fill="#C4D600" d="M60.3,53.7c-8.1,8-21.1,8-29.2,0c-1.5-1.5-3.9-1.5-5.5,0c-1.5,1.5-1.5,3.9,0,5.5c11,11.1,28.8,11.2,39.9,0.2                                  c0.1-0.1,0.1-0.1,0.2-0.2c1.5-1.5,1.5-3.9,0-5.5C64.3,52.2,61.8,52.2,60.3,53.7L60.3,53.7z"></path>
<circle fill="#C4D600" cx="62.4" cy="32.6" r="4"></circle>
<circle fill="#C4D600" cx="29.4" cy="32.6" r="4"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Perfecto, entiendo muy bien, pero sabes? no me está funcionando esta validación if (colorFill !== undefined || colorFill !== 'none') {
        $(this).css('fill', 'red');
      } no entiendo por que, se supone que toma una o la otra pero por alguna razón solo lee el undefined o el none

Comment: que querias hacer realmente con esa condicion que le estableciera un color si el atributo fill es diferente de undefined o de none. Si es eso, uno de ellos abarca al otro a la misma vez con el or, debes ver si te combiene mas usar el &&, o explicarme mejor que querias hacer para poder ayudarte

Comment: Correcto, es or ya que puede tener el "fill='none'" o no tener esta etiqueta que retornará el "undefined"

Comment: Y porke no preguntas si (colorFill && colorFill !== 'none') ?? y me cuentas que tal te va

Comment: Amigo, si funcionó! muchas gracias

Comment: No hay de que para eso estamos :)